# I can't put a box inside a box plus color not changing

Tags: css, box

On the main page of my site there are 4 hyperlinks that I want to appear on every page in the same way. Except I want the link of the page I'm on to be the same color as when I put my mouse on it.

I thought I could get that with this code:

```css
.navigation {
  padding: 40px 0px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.navigation a {
  background: black;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 7px;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 100px 35px;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0.75;
  font-family: impact;
}

.navigation a:hover {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: black;
}

#contact {
  background: white !important;
  color: black !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
  <a href="./productions.html">Mes productions</a>
  <a href="./DJ.html">DJ</a>
  <a target="_blank" href="./CV.pdf">Mon CV</a>
  <div id="contact">
    <a href="./contact.html">Me contacter</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Problem is that it keeps the black background color with white font color and it goes under the other links and not inline with them.

Comment: You assign styles to a container with id="contact". But the link has link styles

Comment: i'm sorry i don't understand your answer

Comment: i know it already has link styles but i thought it would'nt matter with an id and the !important

Comment: I'm sorry. My English is not very good:D If you want to assign a style for a link, just write `#contact a {...}` This way you override the style for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But I think that it's a bad practice to place the link in the "div" in this situation. You can simply register a class for the link and compose styles for this class.

```css
.navigation {
  padding: 40px 0px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.navigation a {
  background: black;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 7px;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 100px 35px;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0.75;
  font-family: impact;
}

.navigation a:hover {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: black;
}

#contact a {
  background: white !important;
  color: black !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
  <a href="./productions.html">Mes productions</a>
  <a href="./DJ.html">DJ</a>
  <a target="_blank" href="./CV.pdf">Mon CV</a>
  <div id="contact">
    <a href="./contact.html">Me contacter</a>
  </div>
</div>
```